# %files section of Singularity recipe non-intuitively copies files to wrong bind location

Tags: singularity-container

I am working on CentOS 8 and am using Singularity 3.6.2.  I have a Singularity recipe file :

```
BootStrap: yum
OSVersion: 8
MirrorURL: http://mirror.centos.org/centos-8/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/
Include: yum

%files
/gpfs0/home1/group/user/path/to/some.rpm /tmp

%post
    ls /tmp
    echo "Hello from inside the container"
```

When I run :

```
$ sudo singularity build test.simg tmp
INFO:    Starting build...
INFO:    Skipping GPG Key Import
INFO:    Adding owner write permission to build path: /tmp/rootfs-4db1e756-22a8-11eb-bb20-34800d2d90f0
INFO:    Copying /gpfs0/home1/group/user/path/to/some.rpm to /tmp/rootfs-4db1e756-22a8-11eb-bb20-34800d2d90f0/tmp
INFO:    Running post scriptlet
+ ls /tmp
qtsingleapp-RStudi-c679-6387e228-lockfile
rootfs-4db1e756-22a8-11eb-bb20-34800d2d90f0
rootfs-b10ad12c-229a-11eb-85a3-34800d2d90f0
+ echo 'Hello from inside the container'
Hello from inside the container
INFO:    Creating SIF file...
```

According to the Singularity [documentation](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.6/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html)

> In the default configuration, the system default bind points are $HOME , /sys:/sys , /proc:/proc, /tmp:/tmp,

**Question** :

1. Why is the `%files` section putting my rpm in `/tmp/rootfs-4db1e756-22a8-11eb-bb20-34800d2d90f0/tmp` and not in `/tmp`?  That seems to contradict the documentation. This is also different from the behavior observed with Singularity v2.5.1
2. Also, how would I access said file. The long 'hash-like' part of the path seems to change depending on the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an answer reconciling the documentation with where the `%files` section is actually putting the files, however I do have an answer for how to access the files copied.  You need to use `${SINGULARITY_CONTAINER}` in the `%post` section.

E.g.

```
$ cat Singularity
BootStrap: yum
OSVersion: 8
MirrorURL: http://mirror.centos.org/centos-8/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/
Include: yum

%files
# Will need to use environmental variables to copy the code to
/gpfs0/home/group/user/path/to/some.rpm /tmp

%post
    ls ${SINGULARITY_CONTAINER}/tmp
    echo "Hello from inside the container"
```

When building yields :

```
$ sudo singularity build tmp.simg tmp
INFO:    Starting build...
INFO:    Skipping GPG Key Import
INFO:    Adding owner write permission to build path: /tmp/rootfs-e2a3fbb4-242b-11eb-a267-34800d2d90f0
INFO:    Copying /gpfs0/home/group/user/path/to/some.rpm to /tmp/rootfs-e2a3fbb4-242b-11eb-a267-34800d2d90f0/tmp
INFO:    Running post scriptlet
+ ls /tmp/rootfs-e2a3fbb4-242b-11eb-a267-34800d2d90f0/tmp
some.rpm
+ echo 'Hello from inside the container'
Hello from inside the container
INFO:    Creating SIF file...
```